# When trying to index in elasticsearch 7.8.1, an error occurs saying "field" is too large, must be <= 32766 Is there a solution?

Tags: elasticsearch

When trying to index in elasticsearch 7.8.1, an error occurs saying "testField" is too large, must be <= 32766 Is there a solution?

Field Info

"testField":{
"type": "keyword",
"index": false
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [known issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/60329) and it is not clear yet on what is best to solve it. Lucene enforces a maximum term length of 32766, beyond which the document is rejected.

Until this gets solved, there are two immediate options you can choose from:

A. Use a [`script` ingest processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.8/script-processor.html) to truncate the value to at most 32766 bytes.

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/truncate-pipeline
{
  "description": "truncate",
  "processors": [
    {
      "script": {
        "source": """
          ctx.testField = ctx.testField.substring(0, 32766);
        """
      }
    }
  ]
}

PUT my-index/_doc/123?pipeline=truncate-pipeline
{ "testField": "hgvuvhv....sjdhbcsdc" }
```

B. Use a `text` field with an appropriate analyzer that would [`truncate`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.8/analysis-truncate-tokenfilter.html) the value, but you'd lose the ability to aggregate and sort on that field.

If you want to keep your field as a `keyword`, I'd go with option A